# Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. how do i fix it?

Tags: asp.net, editing

this line is getting the error message how do i fix it?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RefCode3" runat="server" Width="400px" Font-Size="10px" ForeColor="#9e9e9e" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#D2D2D2"TextMode="MultiLine" Height="40px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a space after `BorderColor`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RefCode3" runat="server" Width="400px" Font-Size="10px" ForeColor="#9e9e9e" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#D2D2D2" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="40px"></asp:TextBox>
```